# Telegram bot не пингует то что мне нужно по запросу

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Написал в Python бота для телеграмм, чтобы он пинговал адреса по запросу пользователя.
Но почему то постоянно ответ приходит один и тот же мой user id.
Собственно сам код:

```
import os
import telebot

token = '*тут я указал токен своего бота*'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    hostname = str(message.chat.id)
    response = os.system('ping ' + hostname)
    if response == 0:
        print(hostname + ' is up!')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hostname + ' is up!')
    else:
        print(hostname + ' is down!')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, hostname + ' is down!')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Вас тут ничего не смущает? ```hostname = str(message.chat.id)```

Comment: А как нужно правильно написать ?

Comment: Таким образом бот принимает сообщение от пользователя ip адрес который нужно пропинговать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таким образом он принимает не айпи адрес, а айди чата в котором он получил сообщение.

```
hostname = str(message.text)
```

Comment: Ура. Всё заработало как нужно. Спасибо вам большое за помощь.